# VBA / Visual Basic. Simple String SQL

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

I'm creating a Voting System. so it's like this every time A Button1 is pressed + 1 or it will increase the vote in the Access  database. I can't find anything in Google.

```
trx = "update [Table1] SET [Vote] = Vote + 1, (WHERE ID = 1)"
```

Comment: What's the question? Where do you get stuck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't include a comma before the `WHERE` clause.  Also you don't need to put the `WHERE` clause inside parentheses.

Test this as a new query in the Access query designer.

```sql
update [Table1] SET [Vote] = Vote + 1 WHERE ID = 1
```

Fine tune as needed.  And once you have it working in the query designer, adapt your VBA code to use that working statement.

Answer (score 1):

Remove comma before Where and brackets around `where clause`

```
trx = "update [Table1] SET [Vote] = Vote + 1 WHERE ID = 1"
```